# Failed to start MariaDB 10.6.7 database server

Tags: mysql, mariadb

● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.6.7 database server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
└─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-04-29 18:28:08 EET; 37s ago
Docs: man:mariadbd(8)
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
Main PID: 8055 (code=exited, status=7)
Status: "MariaDB server is down"

أبر 29 18:28:08 -server mariadbd[8055]: 2022-04-29 18:28:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '/www/server/data/ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writin>
أبر 29 18:28:08 -server mariadbd[8055]: 2022-04-29 18:28:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: File '/www/server/data/ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
أبر 29 18:28:08 -server mariadbd[8055]: 2022-04-29 18:28:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.6.7 started; log sequence number 3145944; transaction id 1282
أبر 29 18:28:08 -server mariadbd[8055]: 2022-04-29 18:28:08 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
أبر 29 18:28:08 -server mariadbd[8055]: 2022-04-29 18:28:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /www/server/data/ib_buffer_pool
أبر 29 18:28:08 -server mariadbd[8055]: 2022-04-29 18:28:08 0 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mariadbd: unknown variable 'early-plugin-load='
أبر 29 18:28:08 -server mariadbd[8055]: 2022-04-29 18:28:08 0 [ERROR] Aborting
أبر 29 18:28:08 -server systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=7/NOTRUNNING
أبر 29 18:28:08 -server systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
أبر 29 18:28:08 -server systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.6.7 database server.
~
~

Comment: ubuntu not microsoft

Comment: [tag:sql-server] is for a very specific product by Microsoft, not just "well my server uses SQL"... the tag even says `Do not use this tag for other types of DBMS (MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, etc.).`